# Allow users to hide the automatic flags, or hide them automatically

Tags: feature-request, automatic-flagging, 10k-tools

There are some flags that are automatically generated, and that a normal user cannot dismiss as valid. As they don't influence the flag weight of the Community user, it doesn't also make sense to flag them as invalid, which would also not be true for the flag created when a user writes the same answer for two different questions.

I think it would be preferable, for the users, to be able to hide them.

[image: screenshot]

As alternative, those flags should be hidden automatically, when the users see it for the third time. The flag should be hidden only for the user who sees them three time; another user that would see it for the first time would not have the flag hidden.

Comment: I've never seen this screen, does it need special reputation ?

Comment: Your reputation should be at least 10000, to see the flag page, which lists the posts flagged from other users. Then, just moderators are able to see all the flags.